# Probability of index at which sequence stops decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

> Let $X_1,X_2, \dots $ be a sequence of independent and identically
>   distributed continuous random variables. Let $N \ge 2$  be such that
>   $X_1 \ge  X_2 \ge X_{N-1} < X_N$.  That is, $N$ is the point at which
>   the sequence stops decreasing. Find $P\{N \ge n\}$. (**Hint**: show $E[N] = e$).

My approach to this problem has been to say that the event $\{ N \ge n \}$ is the same as the event $\{X_1 \ge X_2 \dots \ge X_{n-1} \ge X_n\}$. If this is correct (although please correct me if I'm mistaken), then it is not so obvious to me what the probability of that event is. So I was going to find the probability of small subsets of the event first. For example, find  $P\{X_1 \ge X_2 \}$,  or $P\{X_{j-2} \ge X_{j-1} \ge X_{j} \}$. But I am not so sure about the answer to these simple cases either. Is $P\{X_1 \ge X_2 \} = \frac{1}{2}$? How would you reason to find  $P\{X_{j-2} \ge X_{j-1} \ge X_{j} \}$?

Or, how else would you think about this problem to find $P\{N \ge n \}$?

Comment: I think you have some typos (order going the wrong way?) in the problem statement.

Comment: @universalset I see. Let me edit that. I also left out the **hint** which I just added to the problem statement.

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but could you let me know how you calculated that $\mathbb{E}[N]=e$? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the event ${N\geq n}$ is the same as the event ${X_1 \geq X_2 \geq \cdots \geq X_{n-1}}$.  Since the random variables are continuous, the probability that any two $X_i$ are equal is $0$, so with probability $1$, all of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{n-1}$ are different.  So from now on we'll suppose that they are all different.

Since the variables are independent and identically distributed, each of the $(n-1)!$ orderings of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{n-1}$ are equally likely by symmetry.  It follows that $P(N\geq n) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out at least two things I missed. First, $N \ge n$ is the same as the event $X_1 \ge X_2 \dots \ge X_{n-1}$ not $X_1 \ge X_2 \dots \ge X_{n}$.  Second, that the probability that any two $X_i$ are equal is $0$, so $X_1, X_2, \dots X_{n-1}$ are all different.